# How to apply an uploaded image to a background-image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image, filereader

I'm using standard jQuery to upload an image, and I would like it to apply as the background image of the header. Background-image should receive 'url' and not 'src' attribute, so is it still possible to obtain?

jQuery code:

```
function uploadImage(input){
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
         $('#home-section').attr('background-image...???', e.target.result);
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

`#home-section` is the id given to the header. I know I also can use a regular img tag and then just play with z-indexes to make it function like a background image, but is that the only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply wrap the result Data-URL in a `url()` function for the CSS. Also use `style` as attribute name:

```js
$('#home-section').attr('style', 'background-image:url(' + e.target.result + ')');
```

A better approach however is to use the File object (Blob) with Object-URL. This is faster and leaves a smaller memory footprint. And as a bonus you can drop the `Filereader` altogether:

```js
function uploadImage(input){
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    $('#home-section').attr('style', 'background-image:url(' + url + ')');
  }
}
```

```js
function uploadImage(input){
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
     $('#home-section').attr('style', 'background-image:url(' + url + ')');
    }
}

document.querySelector("input").onchange = function(){uploadImage(this)};
```

```css
#home-section {width:640px; height:480px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select image: <input type=file></label><br>
<div id=home-section></div>
```

Comment: Hey Epistemex thanks a lot that's very helpful and nice to know about this better method